# C++: Template member functions, as in template<typename T> int foo<T>()

Tags: c++, class, templates

I want to define member functions using templates, in a class which is not a template:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        int doThing(T thing, int num);
};
```

This works. But what I want to do is this:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        int doThing<T>(int num);
};
```

With this, I get `error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token`. I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't? Changing `typename` to `class` doesn't make any difference.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Edit: More detail as requested: what I want to achieve is to collapse this repetitive code:

```
class Blob {
    public:
        int read_int8(lua_State *Lua, int offset);
        int read_uint8(lua_State *Lua, int offset);
        int read_int16(lua_State *Lua, int offset);
        int read_uint16(lua_State *Lua, int offset);
        //...
};

int Blob::read_int8(lua_State *Lua, int offset) {
    int8_t *ptr = (int8_t*)this->data;
    lua_pushinteger(Lua, ptr[offset]);
    return 1;
}

int Blob::read_uint8(lua_State *Lua, int offset) {
    uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t*)this->data;
    lua_pushinteger(Lua, ptr[offset]);
    return 1;
}

int Blob::read_int16(lua_State *Lua, int offset) {
    int16_t *ptr = (int16_t*)this->data;
    lua_pushinteger(Lua, ptr[offset]);
    return 1;
}

int Blob::read_uint16(lua_State *Lua, int offset) {
    uint16_t *ptr = (uint16_t*)this->data;
    lua_pushinteger(Lua, ptr[offset]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `<T>` altogether.

Comment: Don't tell us the syntax you want to use; tell us what you want to achieve with that syntax.

Comment: What I want is to have multiple versions of `doThing(int num)`, each of which use a different type internally. I'll edit the post with more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `<T>`.

```
class Foo {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        int doThing(int num);
};
```

Comment: Aha, I didn't think it would be so simple! (Though this doesn't explain how to instantiate the template, but I discovered that easily enough: `myFoo->doThing<int>(myNum)`)